# how to use a Grails DetachedCriteria as its own criteria

Tags: grails, subquery, grails-orm, detachedcriteria

I want to get all rows that match some arbitrary criteria, then I want to also include any rows whose id is the parentId for any of those rows.

```
def criteria = MovieWorkbook.whereAny {
    and { 
        ilike("name", name)
        or {
            eq("status", "open")
            eq("status", "pending")
        }
    }
}

// this fails - returns nothing
criteria.or {
    inList("id", criteria.list()*.parentId )
}
criteria.list()
```

Comment: Does it have to be a detached query? Have you looked at named queries and chaining them? http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html

Comment: Yes, the query needs to be composed dynamically at invocation, something which I don't think is supported by a named query.  In my example, name is supplied by a variable.  In my actual problem, several fields are supplied by loops and variables.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a named query can dynamically build it's criteria  based upon the parameters. e.g. eq(somePropertyName, someValue)

Comment: Sure, but during static initialization.  I can't find any documentation on what syntax would be required to create a namedQuery at runtime, nor pass in parameters as though the namedQuery were a method.

Comment: Not only does the documentation show examples of using parameters (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) but there are some SO posts too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947481/dynamically-creating-a-query-based-on-params-being-passed-to-a-controller You can do anything you would normally in a criteria in a named query. Including composing it dynamically based on the parameters.

Comment: Ah!  I finally see the example where pageCount is a parameter.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Makes sense once I realize a namedQuery is "just" a closure.  So, I'm back to essentially my original question:  how to use a namedCriteria as its own criteria.  I see how to chain them together in a logical AND.  I don't see a logical OR, which is what I need -- "give me stuff, plus, that same stuff's parents."  Unless you see something I'm overlooking (again), I still have to run the query once, then pass its own results back into it as additional criteria.